# Find the probability in 2nd column for a selection in 1st column

Tags: shell, awk

I have two columns as follows

```
ifile.dat
1   10
3   34
1   4
3   32
5   3
2   2
4   20
3   13
4   50
1   40
2   20
5   2
```

I would like to calculate the probability in 2nd column for some selection in 1st column.

```
ofile.dat
1-2   0.417 #Here 1-2 means all values in 1st column ranging from 1 to 2; 
            #0.417 is the probability of corresponding values in 2nd column 
            # i.e. count(10,4,2,40,20)/total = 5/12 
3-4   0.417 #count(34,32,20,13,50)/total = 5/12
5-6   0.167 #count(3,2)/total = 2/12
```

Similarly if I choose the range of selection with 3 number, then the desire output will be

```
ofile.dat
1-3  0.667
4-6  0.333
```

RavinderSingh13 and James Brown had given nice scripts (see answer), but these are not working for lager values than 10 in 1st column.

```
ifile2.txt
10   10
30   34
10   4
30   32
50   3
20   2
40   20
30   13
40   50
10   40
20   20
50   2
```

~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT2:*** Considering OP's edited samples could you please try following. I have tested it successfully with OP's 1st and latest edit samples and it worked perfectly fine with both of them.

Also one more thing, I made this solution such that a "corner case" where range could leave printing elements in case it is NOT crossing range value at last lines. Like OP's 1st sample where `range=2` but max value is `5` so it will NOT leave 5 in here.

```
sort -n Input_file |
awk -v range="2" '
  !b[$1]++{
    c[++count]=$1
  }
  {
    d[$1]=(d[$1]?d[$1] OFS:"")$2
    tot_element++
    till=$1
  }
  END{
    for(i=1;i<=till;i++){
       num+=split(d[i],array," ")
       if(++j==range){
          start=start?start:1
          printf("%s-%s %.02f\n",start,i,num/tot_element)
          start=i+1
          j=num=""
          delete array
       }
       if(j!="" && i==till){
          printf("%s-%s %.02f\n",start,i,num/tot_element)
       }
    }
  }
'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1-10 0.25
11-20 0.17
21-30 0.25
31-40 0.17
41-50 0.17
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** In case your Input_file don't have 2nd column then try following.

```
sort -k1 Input_file |
awk -v range="1" '
  !b[$1]++{
    c[++count]=$1
  }
  {
    d[$1]=(d[$1]?d[$1] OFS:"")$0
    tot_element++
    till=$1
  }
  END{
    for(i=1;i<=till;i+=(range+1)){
       for(j=i;j<=i+range;j++){
          num=split(d[c[j]],array," ")
          total+=num
       }
       print i"-"i+range,tot_element?total/tot_element:0
       total=num=""
    }
  }
'
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
sort -k1 Input_file |
awk -v range="1" '
  !b[$1]++{
    c[++count]=$1
  }
  {
    d[$1]=(d[$1]?d[$1] OFS:"")$2
    tot_element++
    till=$1
  }
  END{
    for(i=1;i<=till;i+=(range+1)){
       for(j=i;j<=i+range;j++){
          num=split(d[c[j]],array," ")
          total+=num
       }
       print i"-"i+range,tot_element?total/tot_element:0
       total=num=""
    }
  }
'
```

---

---

In case you don't have to include any `0` value then try following.

```
sort -k1 Input_file |
awk -v range="1" '
  !b[$1]++{
    c[++count]=$1
  }
  {
    d[$1]=(d[$1]!=0?d[$1] OFS:"")$2
    tot_element++
    till=$1
  }
  END{
    for(i=1;i<=till;i+=(range+1)){
       for(j=i;j<=i+range;j++){
          num=split(d[c[j]],array," ")
          total+=num
       }
       print i"-"i+range,tot_element?total/tot_element:0
       total=num=""
    }
  }
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    a[1]=a[2]=1                 # define the groups here
    a[3]=a[4]=2                 # others will go to an overflow group 3
}
{
    b[(($1 in a)?a[$1]:3)]++    # group 3 defined here
}
END {                           # in the end
    for(i in b)                 # loop all groups in no particular order
        print i,b[i]/NR         # and output
}' file
```

Output

```
1 0.416667
2 0.416667
3 0.166667
```

**Update**. Yet another awk with range configuration file. $1 is the start of range, $2 the end and $3 is the group name:

```
1 3 1-3
4 9 4-9
10 30 10-30
40 100 40-100
```

Awk program:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    OFS="\t"
}
NR==FNR {
    for(i=$1;i<=$2;i++)
        a[i]=$3
    next
}
{
    b[(($1 in a)?a[$1]:"others")]++   # the overflow group is now called "others"
}
END {
    for(i in b)
        print i,b[i]/NR
}' rangefile datafile
```

Output with both your datasets catenated together (and awk output piped to `sort -n`):

```
1-3     0.285714
4-9     0.142857
10-30   0.285714
40-100  0.142857
```

Comment: Thanks James Brown. Could you kindly check it once again with larger values. I have edited the question.

Comment: Surely it will work, you just need to define the groups for each value: `a[10]=a[20]="group 1"` etc

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I understood it now.